# $scope is undefined in Ionic popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to show calculated result in the ionic pop up but somehow I couldn't understand the $scope variable is 'undefined' inside the popup.

```
.controller('HealthCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicPopup){
    $scope.health = {
    weight: '',
    height: ''
  };
    $scope.calculate = function(){
        console.log('calculate button got click event');
        console.log($scope.health.weight);
        var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
          template: '<b> {{0.5 * $scope.health.weight + 16}} </b>',
          title: 'Result',
          scope: $scope,
          buttons: [
            {
              text: '<b>Done</b>',
              type: 'button-positive',
              onTap: function() {
                $state.go('app.record');
              }
            }
          ]
       }).then(function(res){
            console.log(res);
            console.log($scope.health.weight);
       });
    }
})
```

In the above the popup template displays **NaN** because of

> $scope.health.weight

is 'undefined'. Where as the `console.log($scope.health.weight);` in the calculate function displays the proper value. Please suggest.

Comment: replace `$scope.health.weight` with `health.weight` in the `template` string

Comment: @Rovak Thanks a lot this solved the issue. But I see `this.health.weight` also works fine. Any thoughts on that.

Comment: $scope is used to pass value of variable. It is not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`scope` is present inside `$scope.calculate`. So, I don't think you can assign that back to scope. It will become an uninterpretable code. Use only the attributes that you need there not the whole scope .. I think that should resolve your issue...

Comment: Ty for the answer. I didn't understand this part `scope: <What goes here?>` . As `scope: $scope` and template with `health.weight` or `this.health.weight` works fine. However if I remove the `scope` then nothing works. Now can you please tell me `scope: <What goes here?>`